# Migration Composite Application Block (CAB) .NET 2.0 to 4.5

Tags: wpf, migration, prism, cab

The company I am working in has a ClickOnce application built using .NET 2.0 CAB framework.
As part of the technology refresh cycle the hardware and softwares are being upgraded.

The decision is to migrate the ClickOnce application from .NET 2.0 to 4.5. As mentioned above it is built using the CAB framework.

From googling and reading items from the internet, I concluded the way forward is to migrate to WPF - PRISM framework.

I have some questions that I am not able to get clear answers.

What is the complexity of undertaking such a migration?

Would it involve rewriting the entire application, reusing parts of the code like business layer and data layer?

Alternatively would it make sense to leave the application as it is and only rebuild it targeting the .NET 4.5 framework and fixing errors due to deprecated components?